# How can I get a non-friend to view photos I've been tagged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-photos

I have a friend who cannot be my Facebook friend, but I would like them to be able to view on my timeline any photos that I've been tagged in by others.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your facebook settings > Time line and tagging. Attribute should be **everyone** instead of **Friends**

[image]